# Seeking household income district wise for entire India

Tags: census, india

I need to combine census data with household income data. I was able to obtain census data district wise for entire India and join it with the district-level shapefile, I need data on household income district wise for entire India.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for data from across the country, you need to explore the national statistics site:

http://www.mospi.gov.in/